# Github Actions: SwiftEmitModule normal x86_64 Emitting\ module\ for\

Tags: ios, swift, github-actions

I have this repository: [enter link description here](https://github.com/Shijo64/HikeApp)

its a simple repository, with a newly created ios app, the app deployment target is 15.0, I added a simple test:

```
func testExample() throws {
    
    XCTAssertEqual(2*2, 4)
}
```

and also added only 1 pod:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '15.0'

target 'HikeApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for HikeApp
  pod 'Alamofire'

end
```

and then in the repository i added this workflow:
name: iOS starter workflow

on:
push:
branches: [ "main" ]
pull_request:
branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
build:
name: Build and Test default scheme using any available iPhone simulator
runs-on: macos-latest

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Set Default Scheme
    run: |
      scheme_list=$(xcodebuild -list -json | tr -d "\n")
      default=$(echo $scheme_list | ruby -e "require 'json'; puts JSON.parse(STDIN.gets)['project']['targets'][0]")
      echo $default | cat >default
      echo Using default scheme: $default
  - name: Build
    env:
      scheme: ${{ 'default' }}
      platform: ${{ 'iOS Simulator' }}
    run: |
      # xcrun xctrace returns via stderr, not the expected stdout (see https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663959)
      device=`xcrun xctrace list devices 2>&1 | grep -oE 'iPhone.*?[^\(]+' | head -1 | awk '{$1=$1;print}' | sed -e "s/ Simulator$//"`
      if [ $scheme = default ]; then scheme=$(cat default); fi
      if [ "`ls -A | grep -i \\.xcworkspace\$`" ]; then filetype_parameter="workspace" && file_to_build="`ls -A | grep -i \\.xcworkspace\$`"; else filetype_parameter="project" && file_to_build="`ls -A | grep -i \\.xcodeproj\$`"; fi
      file_to_build=`echo $file_to_build | awk '{$1=$1;print}'`
      xcodebuild build-for-testing -scheme "$scheme" -"$filetype_parameter" "$file_to_build" -destination "platform=$platform,name=$device"
  - name: Test
    env:
      scheme: ${{ 'default' }}
      platform: ${{ 'iOS Simulator' }}
    run: |
      # xcrun xctrace returns via stderr, not the expected stdout (see https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663959)
      device=`xcrun xctrace list devices 2>&1 | grep -oE 'iPhone.*?[^\(]+' | head -1 | awk '{$1=$1;print}' | sed -e "s/ Simulator$//"`
      if [ $scheme = default ]; then scheme=$(cat default); fi
      if [ "`ls -A | grep -i \\.xcworkspace\$`" ]; then filetype_parameter="workspace" && file_to_build="`ls -A | grep -i \\.xcworkspace\$`"; else filetype_parameter="project" && file_to_build="`ls -A | grep -i \\.xcodeproj\$`"; fi
      file_to_build=`echo $file_to_build | awk '{$1=$1;print}'`
      xcodebuild test-without-building -scheme "$scheme" -"$filetype_parameter" "$file_to_build" -destination "platform=$platform,name=$device"
```

but for some reason when i push to the repository and the action executes i get this error:

> The following build commands failed:
> SwiftEmitModule normal x86_64 Emitting\ module\ for\ HikeApp (in target 'HikeApp' from project 'HikeApp')
> (1 failure)
> Error: Process completed with exit code 65.

I dont really know how to solve that, any help?